# Generating a multipart/byterange response without scanning the parts ahead of sending

Tags: http, httpresponse, multipart

I would like to generate a multipart byte range response. Is there a way for me to do it without scanning each segment I am about to send out, since I need to generate multipart boundary strings?

For example, I can have a user request a byterange that would have me fetch and scan 2GB of data, which in my case involves me loading that data into my (slow) VM as strings and so forth. Ideally I would like to simply state in the response that a part has a length of a certain number of bytes, and be done with it. Is there any tooling that could provide me with this option? I see that many developers just grab a UUID as the boundary and are probably willing to risk a tiny probability that it will appear somewhere within the part, but that risk seems to be small enough multiple people are taking it?

To explain in more detail: scanning the parts ahead of time (before generating the response) is not really feasible in my case since I need to fetch them via HTTP from an upstream service. This means that I effectively have to prefetch the entire part first to compute a non-matching multipart boundary, and only then can I splice that part into the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data can be arbitrary, I don’t see how you could guarantee absence of collisions without scanning the data.

If the format of the data is very limited (like... base 64 encoded?), you may be able to pick a boundary that is known to be an illegal sequence of bytes in that format.

Even if your boundary *does* collide with the data, it must be followed by headers such as `Content-Range`, which is even more improbable, so the client is likely to treat it as an error rather than consume the wrong data.

Major Web servers use very simple strategies. Apache [grabs 8 random bytes](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/http/http_core.c?revision=1743699&view=markup#l289) at startup and renders them in hexadecimal. nginx uses [a sequential counter](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/http/modules/ngx_http_range_filter_module.c?rev=6480#L478) left-padded with zeroes.

UUIDs are designed to avoid collisions with *other UUIDs*, not with arbitrary data. A UUID is no more likely to be a good boundary than a completely random string of the same length. Moreover, some UUID variants include information that you may not want to disclose, such as your machine’s MAC address.

> Ideally I would like to simply state in the response that a part has a length of a certain number of bytes, and be done with it. Is there any tooling that could provide me with this option?

Maybe you can avoid supporting multiple ranges and simply tell the clients to request each range separately. In that case, you don’t use the multipart format, so there is no problem.

If you do want to send multiple ranges in one response, then [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233) requires the multipart format, which requires the boundary string.

You can, of course, invent your own mechanism instead of that of RFC 7233. In that case:

- You cannot use [206 (Partial Content)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1). You must use 200 (OK) or some other applicable status code.
- You cannot use the `multipart/byteranges` media type. You must come up with your own media type.
- You cannot use the [`Range`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-3.1) request header.
- Because a 200 (OK) response to a GET request is [supposed to carry a (full) representation of the resource](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.3), you must do one of the following:

  - encode the requested ranges in the URL; or
  - use something like POST instead of GET; or
  - use a custom, non-standard status code instead of 200 (OK); or
  - (not sure if this is a correct approach) use media type parameters, send them in [`Accept`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2), and add `Accept` to [`Vary`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.4).

The [chunked transfer coding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1) may be useful, but you cannot rely on it alone, because it is a property of the connection, not of the payload.

Comment: Currently I do respond with a 416 when the client requests multiple ranges, but I am not sure it is the right response. Another SO question is in order so it seems :-P